# Convert String to Array in Javascript in pair

Tags: javascript

I have a string like

```
var str = "aabbrdfc0912";
```

and i want to convert it in an array in pair of two like

```
var arr = ["aa","bb","rd","fc","09","12"];
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 6):

You could use a regular expression for it.

```js
var str = "aabbrdfc0912",
    array = str.match(/..|./g);
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the possible regex could be `/[\w]{2}/g`

```js
var str = "aabbrdfc0912", splited_arr;

splitted_arr = str.match(/[\w]{2}/g);
console.log(splitted_arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `match` function and a small regex to do that:

```js
var even_str = "aabbrdfc0912",
    odd_str = "aabbrdfc0912X";

console.log( splitInPairs(even_str) );
console.log( splitInPairs(odd_str) );

function splitInPairs(str) {
    return str.match(/..?/g);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`String.match(rg)` would let you do this:

```js
console.log("aabbrdfc0912".match(/\w\w/g))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = str.match(/.{1,2}/g);
```

will give you result

```
["aa","bb","rd","fc","09","12"];
```

Answer (score 0):

> `For-loop` with increment of `2` could be helpful.

```js
var str = "aabbrdfc09123";;
var op = [];
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i += 2) {
  op.push(str[i] + (str[i + 1] || ''));
}
console.log(op);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using `String.split`, `Array.slice` and `Array.forEach` functions:

```
var str = "aabbrdfc0912", result = [];

str.split('').forEach(function(v, k, arr){
   if (k % 2 !== 0) this.push(arr.slice(k-1, k+1).join(''));
}, result);

console.log(result);  // ["aa", "bb", "rd", "fc", "09", "12"]
```

---

And one more approach with `String.split` and `Array.filter` methods:

```
result = str.split(/(\w{2})/).filter(Boolean);

console.log(result);  // ["aa", "bb", "rd", "fc", "09", "12"]
```

Answer (score 0):

well, this can be done like this too instead of regex,

```js
var str = "aabbrdfc0912";
var result = [];
var piece = 2;

while (str.length) {
  result.push(str.slice(0, piece));
  str = str.substr(piece);
}

console.log(result);
// result = ["aa","bb","rd","fc","09","12"];
```